# cannot bind non-const lvalue reference of type 'ClassName &’ to an rvalue of type ‘ClassName’

Tags: c++, class, oop, pointers

This is my Function Prototype:

```
  Rational & operator+=(const Rational &);
```

This is portion of my class:

```
    class Rational
    {
      public:
      Rational(int a = 0, int b = 1) : n(a), d(b) {}
```

This my function:

```
Rational & Rational::operator+=(const Rational & r)
{
  return (r + *this);
}
```

I have already made a function to add two rational numbers. 
When I try to compile it I get the following error:

```
error: cannot bind non-const lvalue reference of type 
‘Rational&’ to an rvalue of type ‘Rational’
   return (r + *this);
```

What did I do wrong?

Comment: It seems that you are unaware of simple trick: googling for error message first is most often good idea...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You operator+ returns a fresh instance, doesn't it? So, what happens in your return statement?

1. You try to return a temporary result (that's what the error message is about).
2. Meanwhile, you haven't modified the this object thus violating += semantics (no, by substituting the result of expression where this's value should be you haven't given a slightest hint to the compiler of your actual intent.)

You know, a more natural implementation would be to put the real math in operator+=, and then reuse it in operator+, something like `R retVal = a; return a += b;`.